# C++ file I/O over a cloud network

Tags: c++, cloud-hosting

I'm developing a cloud site consisting of two instances. One has the web, database and static files. Thats's the main server. The other instance reads files from the main server, run some c++ programs and writes back some new files in the main server. That's the workstation.

What's the best way to I/O the files from the main server to the c++ programs?

I'm considering copying the files temporarily in the workstation using scp. Is there any better alternative?

Comment: Do you want this to happen automatically? If so you have two different directions: push a new file (or notification about it) or pull the server for new files. Once you select an approach you can make a service that will handle communication. In this days people would use REST, some would use SOAP web service. I am not sure if it's possible to use spc in automated manner

Comment: The file paths are saved in the database. The C++ programs look for new files in it. So, I guess it's not necessary to use REST. I guess...